# Android Apps 64-bit Advice - Receiving Contradictory Information

Tags: android, 64-bit

Google requires all apps submitted after August 1 to have 64-bit and 32-bit .so files.  They have an article about how to package both sets of libraries in your .apk

I've been told that instead, we should create 2 apps, one with 32-bit libraries and one with 64-bit libraries, and submit them both with different version codes.  Will this even work?

My understanding is that a 32-bit-only app won't even be accepted after August 1, so how can I submit both?  If I submit the 64-bit one first, will the store be ok with then submitting a 32-bit-only one?

Even more confusing is that I was told to use version codes far apart to distinguish the 32-bit and 64-bit versions.  So today my version code is 32.  In August, I'd submit a 32-bit app with code 33 and a 64-bit one with code 1033.  And then, for another app, I would submit one with codes 34 and 1034.  That doesn't make sense to me, because my understanding is that you can never go backwards in version codes, they always increase in value.

Not that it matters in this context, bit it is Kony (a multi-platform app generator from JavaScript) that is telling us to do it this way.  This advice just doesn't sound right, and I don't want to find out the hard way on August 1 that it isn't going to work.

I've tried to find information on the Google developer site, but I don't see any indication that this strategy will work.

Any clarification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a document on the Android development site that answers everything.
https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html